# Converting an array of bytes to an array of floats

Tags: java, delphi, arrays

I'm currently converting a Delphi method used for random binary file access into Java.  The Delphi procedure uses:

```
TSingleArray  = Array[0..MAXSIZE] of Single
...
procedure GetLinkValues(const LinkVar: Integer;  const TimePeriod: Integer; var Value: PSingleArray);
...
BlockRead(Fout, Value^, Nlinks*SizeOf(Single));
```

To read an array of bytes into an array of Single.  Is there an equivalent way of doing this in Java without iterating through the array?

I’m currently using

```
List<Float> l = new ArrayList<Float>();
…
for (int i = 0 ; i < nLinks ; i++ )
l.add( resultsFile.readFloat());
```

But I’m concerned about speed.  Endianness is not a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you profiled the code and actually found it to be a problem? *Something* is going to have to loop... are you really sure this is a bottleneck in your code?

Having said all that, you should be able to use a FloatBuffer which I suspect does what you want. Unfortunately Sun's JavaDoc is down, so I can't easily link to or check the documentation at the minute.

To use a FloatBuffer, you'd probably want to:

- Create a FileChannel associated with the file  (e.g. with FileInputStream.getChannel)
- Create a ByteBuffer
- Create a FloatBuffer wrapping the ByteBuffer, with ByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer
- Read into the ByteBuffer with FileChannel.read(byteBuffer)
- Read from the FloatBuffer

I'm not particularly familiar/comfortable with java.nio, so I *hope* this is all correct - but it's likely to be pretty fiddly. Your current loop is almost certainly simpler, so I strongly suggest you check the performance of that first! You might want to wrap your current FileInputStream in a BufferedInputStream, btw.

Comment: Works for me, at least the third time I tried. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html

Comment: I think that means that the answer is no.  What I was looking for was a way of replicating the pointer operation in Java, filling an array of Simple (float) with bytes as I believe (perhaps incorrectly) that this avoids iteration.  Later I can read values using myArray[n]

Comment: @GrahamA: You can do block copies using a FloatBuffer, which will be efficient - but then the code will be more complicated. Basically you can have efficiency or simplicity, but not both. Have you tested the simple code for speed yet?

Comment: Profiled using System.currentTimeMillis() and a 65Mb file.  Reading 27446 records.  

List<float> 140 Milliseconds
ByteBuffer 0

Iteration through he list and byte buffer (after conversion to array) is 16ms.  I have tried several different size results files and I’m getting consistent answers.

Comment: Are you making sure that you flush the file system cache first? Otherwise reading it the first time will hit disk and the second won't. Furthermore, is 16ms really a problem for you? Even if ByteBuffer is a lot faster, is this *definitely* a bottleneck for you?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the help provided by Jon the final code looks like this:

```
byte[] bt = new byte[nLinks * 4];
List<Float> l = new ArrayList<Float>();
if (linkVar != 0 && timePeriod < nPeriods) {
    long p1 = RECORDSIZE * (nNodes * NODEVARS + nLinks * LINKVARS);
    long p2 = RECORDSIZE * (nNodes * NODEVARS + nLinks * (linkVar - 1));
    long p3 = offset2 + (timePeriod * p1) + p2;
    resultsFile.seek(p3);

    resultsFile.read(bt, 0, nLinks * 4);
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bt);
    bb.rewind();
    bb.asFloatBuffer().get(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a loop somewhere - whether it is your own, or internally inside a buffer copy method/operation.  The only way of speeding things up beyond that is to find hardware and a compiler that supports vector operations.